# object play not found in scala application

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Eclipse and create a new Scala object, want to use json parsing feature of play and import this package, but there is error object play cannot be found. Wondering how to use play library in a Scala object?

This is how I import,

```
import play.api.libs.json._
```

Post picture how I create the project.

[image]

[image]

regards,
Lin

Comment: Did you added the `json` dependency?

Comment: @marcospereira, what do you mean? More details are appreciated.

Comment: Post your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: @marcospereira, thanks. I do not find build.sbt and I post how I create the Scala project in Eclipse. Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, you just had created a scala project and not a Play project. See  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication

Comment: @marcospereira, do I have to create a play project in order to use libraries in play? Thanks.

Comment: No ([see this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout)) but it have to be a [SBT project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html) which will have a `build.sbt` file or a `project/Build.scala` file.

Comment: @marcospereira, thanks for sharing the details. I am following the document you referred, but it seems there is no `activator` command for me? Do I need to install something? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the play docs are suffice and you won't need my help here. ;-)

Comment: @marcospereira, this one? playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication

Comment: @marcospereira, I am following your advice to install Play. Follow this guide => https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing, there is step to add activator into PATH, `export PATH=/path/to/activator-x.x.x:$PATH`, I install to `~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9`, shall I add `~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9` to PATH or add `~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9/bin` to PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Play's Scala Json library in an ordinary scala project, not a Play project, you need to import the library in `build.sbt` or `project/Build.scala`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.5.2"
```

and run

```
$ sbt update
```

This instructs the SBT to fetch the scala library `play-json` from a remote Maven repository. The line above is the same as is found on the "SBT" tab of the repository viewer page: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/2.5.2#sbt

Now that you have added the library into your project, you can import and use it in your code such as `src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala`:

```
package com.example

import play.api.libs.json._

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
      {
        "name" : "Watership Down",
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 51.235685,
          "long" : -1.309197
        },
        "residents" : [ {
          "name" : "Fiver",
          "age" : 4,
          "role" : null
        }, {
          "name" : "Bigwig",
          "age" : 6,
          "role" : "Owsla"
        } ]
      }
    """)
    println(json)
  }
}
```

You will be better off learning basic stuff about SBT at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html

Comment: Play has a `json` variable to declare the dependency, so you just need to write `libraryDependencies += json`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks mmizutani for the solution, vote up, for the alternative solution @marcospereira mentioned of building a native play project, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: @marcospereira, nice catch and vote up. Comparing the solution provided by mmizutani, what are the pros and cons of your solution of building a native pure play project if I just need to use the play libraries -- no UI needed? Thanks.

Comment: Hi mmizutani , I am follow this guide => https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing, there is step to add activator into PATH, `export PATH=/path/to/activator-x.x.x:$PATH`, I install to `~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9`, shall I add `~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9` to PATH or add `~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9/bin` to PATH?

Comment: @Lin Ma
It is better to move the folder `activator-dist-1.3.9` from `~/Downloads`, which is usually for temporary files, to a directory like `~/` and `~/bin`. After that, to install the Lightbend Activator, you need to add to PATH the bin subfolder `activator-dist-1.3.9/bin`, not the root directory of the unzipped folder `activator-dist-1.3.9`.

    `mv ~/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.9 ~/activator-dist-1.3.9`
    `export PATH=~/activator-dist-1.3.9/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Some people install Activator via Homebrew/Linuxbrew as the installation and upgrade of Activator are a bit tedious.

Comment: Thanks @mmizutani, vote up and what is Lightbend Activator? Is it `activator-dist-1.3.9`? Thanks.

Comment: @Lin Ma, yes, what you have downloaded and have been using, activator-dist-1.3.9, is [Lightbend Activator](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt).

Comment: Thanks @mmizutani, why it is called Lightbend? Does it mean there are many types of activator (Activator is kinds of standard), and Lightbend is one of the specific implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the help mmizutani, mark your reply as answer.