# Scala "not found: object com" - should i really add entry in build.sbt if there are no other dependencies?

Tags: scala, playframework, ivy

I have created basic Scala Play application with https://www.playframework.com/getting-started play-scala-seed. This project compiles and runs with `sbt run`. But I have another Scala project that compiles and runs and which I have submitted to my local Ivy repository with command `sbt publishLocal`. This other project was saved at `C:\Users\tomr\.ivy2\local\com.agiintelligence\scala-isabelle_2.13\master-SNAPSHOT` as a result of this command.

Then I imported (exactly so - imported, no just opened) my Play project in IntelliJ and I used `Project - Open Module Settings - Project Settings - Libraries` to add com.agiintelligence jar from my ivy2 location. After such operations IntelliJ editor recognizes com.agiintelligence classes. That is fine.

But when I am trying to run my Play application with `sbt run`, I experience the error message `not found: object com` that is exactly when compiling `import com.agiintelligence` line in my Scala controller file of Play application.

Of course - such error has been reported and resolved with, e.g. [object play not found in scala application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658125/object-play-not-found-in-scala-application)
But that solution suggests to append build.sbt file. My build.sbt file is pretty bare:

```
name := """agiintelligence"""
organization := "com.agiintelligence"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.5"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test

// Adds additional packages into Twirl
//TwirlKeys.templateImports += "com.skaraintelligence.controllers._"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
// play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport += "com.skaraintelligence.binders._"
```

My Play application contains (as can bee seen from the IntelliJ project pane) some tens of 'external libraries' (it shows my com.agiintelligence jar as well), but why should I add my own ivy2 library in build.sbt file if no other libraries are listed here? What is different with my library? It is on my computer, in the repository as expected already?

Of course, I can try to add it build.sbt and issue `sbt update` and see what happens, but I can not understand this logic? Can someone explain it and provide some clue to intelligible solution of my error message?

Comment: Does your application depend on `com.agiintelligence`? Then list it in the dependencies. Why the question? *"It is on my computer, in the repository as expected already"* - this is fine, then `sbt` won't have to download anything extra. This does not change the fact that your application depends on `com.agiintelligence`.

Comment: If there appears at least one more close vote, then I will delete my question. I am not sure who will benefit from the deletion of my question, but I will delete it. My opinion is that community can benefit from the suggestion and explanation in this QA, sometimes every hint and suggestion is so valuable when narrowing down the problem and tryin to solve. OMG, as a developer I know it! But if community is closevoting this information, then I will definitely delete it, I don't need close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Play application contains (as can bee seen from the IntelliJ project pane) some tens of 'external libraries'

Those are probably just transitive dependencies of your **Play** dependency, that is why **sbt** downloaded all of them and put them in your classpath so you could use them without you needing to tell it about them; because the `pom` of **Play** already did.
It is not that the build tool or the IDE magically added all those dependencies for you because they read your mind and magically understood you wanted them. And that for some reason the magic stopped working for your own library.

> Why it is not sufficient to list it Project-Setting--External Libraries in IntelliJ only?

That is sufficient for the IDE to work, but not for the build tool. The build tool is independent of the IDE; it doesn't know about it. **sbt** just knows about the dependencies you configured in your definition file.

Even more, you should always configure your dependencies on your build tool and then import that in the IDE; rather than the opposite. IDEs are graphical tools, so their state can not be committed, can not be shared, can not keep track of changes, can not be used in CI / CD environments; additionally, different teammates may want to use different IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error message by adding line in `build.sbt` file

libraryDependencies += "de.unruh" %% "scala-isabelle" % "master-SNAPSHOT"

and by subsequent run of `sbt update`.

Error is solved, but the main question still stand - why I had to do this? Why there are tens of dependencies that are not listed in build.sbt and why should I list my dependency in build.sbt and why it is not sufficient to list it `Project-Setting--External Libraries` in IntelliJ only?

OK, comment by @Luis_Miguel_Mejía_Suárez gave the explanation, that comment is the actual and expected answer to my question.